# Netstat shows a VNC port that I didn't open...should I be worried?

Tags: vnc

While sleuthing something else I ran Netstat and noticed there are 2 VNC ports open, one that I recognize (5900) and one that I don't (6008).

Is there any way to tell what's ON this 6008?  Can I view it myself?

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3111/Xtightvnc
```

Is this a normal part of the VNC process?  Anything else I should know?

Answer (score 1):

TCP port 6000 and up (X11 protocol), is where applications communicate with `xtightvnc` (or any other X11 server) in order to display their GUI.

Comment: So this actually would be something normal, connected to my 5900 session, and I shouldn't worry about it.  :-)  Yes?

Comment: Yes, this is normal. Since this is a program listening on all your network interfaces for TCP connections, you will want to make sure that nobody unauthorized can connect. Your local firewall and the `xhost` (X server built-in access control) will help with that. `xhost` should say `access control enabled` and only list users and hosts you would want to be able to display things on your X/VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

The VNC standard is to use TCP port 5900 + the VNC desktop number.  That can be zero, or one, or, less commonly, higher numbers.  e.g., for VNC desktop number 7, the standard is TCP port 5907.  Although perhaps not an official standard, I don't typically see VNC desktop numbers above 99.

There is another standard for VNC, which is 5800 + the VNC desktop number.  That is used for "Java" viewer compatibility support.

Check your VNC server software for such options.

TCP port 6000 and higher are X Window desktops/sessions.  (Unrelated to VNC.)  Details on how this is configured can be impacted by what X Window software you're using.